# React return within render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I'm making changes to an existing code base.
Below is a snippet of the code with details hidden:

```
class Config extends Component {
  .
  .
  .
  render() {
    const { onSubmit, isConfigValid } = this.props;

    return (
      <Form>
        .
        .
        .
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

I need to change the `<Form>` component to a `<Dialog>` component and the implementation notes for this component give an example usage as:

```
render(
  <Dialog>
    .
    .
    .  
  </Dialog>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

How do I incorporate this into the current format where there is a return within the render?
I have tried simply replacing the `<Form>` tags with `<Dialog>` tags but I don't know where to put the `document.getElementById('root')` and the Dialog box appears in the wrong position without this.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Just return a `Dialog` component. The example is using the dialog as the root component to ReactDOM.render(…)

Comment: 2nd `render` seems to be [ReactDOM.render](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render) since that's where you specify the container to show the component.

Comment: You could just create a new `Dialog` component and return it whenever you need.

Comment: @Li357 but what about `document.getElementById('root')`, where does that go

Comment: @tnoel999888 The example is using `ReactDOM.render`. If you have a standalone component then you don't need it (provided that you actually render the component in the first place)

Comment: @Li357 I can get the component being rendered by just putting `<Dialog>` instead of `<Form>`, but it attaches to the component in which I'm writing the code, instead of the root component, I assumed the `document.getElementById('root')` bit specifies which element the component should attach to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see you use `ReactDOM.render(...)` where you want to render your top component into the DOM. Here, it is `Config`.

```js
class Config extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      //<Form>, Instead use <Dialog> here
      <Dialog>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <p>Foo</p>
      </Dialog>
      //</Form>
    );
  }
}

// Instead of using in the same file, probably you will import it:
// import Dialog from "./where_is_this_Dialog";
const Dialog = (props) => (
  <div>{props.children}</div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Config />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However I'm getting a message "ESLint: 'children' is missing in props validation (react/prop-types)". I don't really understand the `const Dialog = (props) => (...` bit, I've already imported Dialog, do I still need this bit of code in that case?

Comment: For prop types, it is a warning for the children I passed to `Dialog` component. I did this because you exampled this component like it waits some children. If you show us `Dialog` component we can make better suggestions. For the last question, of course you don't need the `const Dialog ...` part, I just mimicked your component here. You will import it then use it.